# How the square model of Fano 3-space, a.k.a. $PG(3, 2)$, embeds in the MOG?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

I'm studying deeply the Curtis' MOG original article, i.e. a New combinatorial approach to $M_{24}$ and I'm still struggling a bit in reading the final 35 6x4 matrices representing the MOG.
Actually it's clear to me they are split into a **brick** made by 2 1x4 columns and which are gotten collecting the 35 arrangements of a 8-set into couples of tetrads. Here the black and white squares are related to the $GF(2)$ entries.
The right part of the 6x4 matrix is 4x4 square, which contains 4 symbols per square. Actually this highly reminds me the $PG(3, 2)$ square model, as depicted here:
[The square model of Fano 3-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PG(3,2)#/media/File:150614-PG-3-2-schoolgirls-arrangement.png)

Since this is made by 35 entries too, I really think there's a strong connection with the squares in the MOG, even if different. This is also suggested in many places by Cullinane in his Finite geometry site. The point is not clear to me how to interpret those 4 symbols. I guess they are taken from $GF(4)$ but I cannot see a clear mapping with the symbols.

I know from SPLAG Conway produced yet another representation of the MOG, using the Hexacode and $GF(4)$, but this approach was not present in the original seminal Curtis article, so I cannot see how those $GF(4)$ entries are gotten there.

Thank for the help.

EDIT: I've rephrased the title question to better representing my doubt.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Of course the diagram of the "square model"  is the same as the right $4\times4$ square in Curtis's MOG, but what the MOG does is pair up these $35$ squares with the $35$ ways of partitioning an eight-element set into two four-element blocks.

Comment: "of course the diagram". This is the problem: I cannot see that "of course". Can you explain why they are the same? There's not any explicit reference to $PG(3,2)$ in Curtis' article. Actually it starts using $GF(2)$ with $dim=24$, and the brick tetrad are represented by just 2 symbols, which makes sense. But why there square tetrad are a $PG(3,2)$ embedding? So understanding how that diagram is gotten could help in understanding the MOG as well, probably. I just found a possible explanation of it from Cullinane http://finitegeometry.org/sc/pg/dt/ortholatin.html

Comment: I don't think there is any significance in the four symbols save that they are four distinct symbols. You can identify the 16 little squares with points of $V=(\Bbb F_2)^4$ and each subdiagram shows a plane in $V$ through the origin (a dimension two linear subspace of $V$) and the three other planes parallel to it.

Comment: your comment above forced me to rephrase the title question, which now became "how the square model embeds in the MOG?". Reading the MOG article, the square part of it is gotten as $\Lambda_2+\Lambda_3$ and this is clear. However, the article assumes all the actors live in $GF(2)$, so I cannot see how there can be four symbols here.